# Scaling Images for mdpi

Tags: android

I am working on scaling images for my app to make them look great for every screen. I think I follow the different scales for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, etc. The trouble I am having is that the smaller mdpi images are called for the 10.1" tablet making them appear far too small for the large screen size.

For example, I have a play button with the following sizes:

- MDPI: 200px x 200px
- HDPI: 300px x 300px
- XHDPI: 400px x 400px
- XXHDPI: 600px x 600px

And the 200px play button is being called to the 10" tablet.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you placing the assets? What resolution is your tablet? (if you don't know, download the free and excellent ScreenInfo app by Jotabout)

Comment: Hi 323go. I'm placing the images in the 4 drawable folders listed in the question. The resolution is 1280 x 800 (I'm viewing the graphical layout for the 10.1" tablet). It looks like according to the answer from @Ganesh I need to add more than the 4 default folders?

Comment: Casey, what you should see is that all the images appear to be the same *physical* size, regardless of screen-size. That is what the resolution folders are for. Your assets as listed above should be 1 1/4" square on all device resolutions -- you just get more pixels at higher resolutions to take advantage of the smaller pixels. If you want different sizes (and I might have misread your question initially), then you should follow Ganesh's advice and target the screen sizes. Size and resolution are different (although correlated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for tablet, the images has taken from **drawable-xlarge** folder.

The tablet has mdpi. if the image is not in xlarge folder, its get from mdpi folder.

So use xlarge folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes for 7" you must use drawable-large and for 10.1" drawable-xlarge

Comment: Better use `drawable-xlarge-mdpi`, otherwise the screen resolution is not taken into account when selecting the image.

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh. So I need to make two more drawable folders called drawable-xlarge-mdpi and drawable-large-mdpi and place the same mdpi images in these folders? Are there more drawable folders I should be using if I want to make sure I am supporting every screen size and resolution?